# Why is it almost impossible to find a property in UK that accepts pets?

Tags: united-kingdom, relocation, pets, lease

I've been looking for the last three weeks to get a place to rent in north Kent, as I have to move there for work, and it's **impossible** to find a property that accepts cats – *I'm having two adorable and clean cats* – and is **decent**.

Out of a selection of more than 40 properties (for which financially I'd be amongst the top candidates), on which I was really liking 20, I could only get to visit 3 properties, and those 3 properties were not even decent. Old carpets that look like being more than 10 years old, single glazed windows, kitchen and bathroom not having been updated since last century.

I'm actually trying to get something that is equivalent or better than what I already got, and I'm leaving in central Paris where the rents are in the world's top 10.

All in all, I'm almost feeling discriminated because I'm having pets and I do love them!

So, that's all for the rant, but really, why landlords enforce such a policy in UK? Even though I agree animals *can* do damages (but humans *can* do worst), that's also the reason why we give a deposit to cover any extra cleaning or repairing cost!

And what would happen if I say I'm not bringing my cats in, but I actually do? Can I be expelled because of the breach in the contract? And isn't there any law that can protect the tenant to host whoever and whatever he wants during the time of the lease, like we do have in France?

Comment: Are you looking at flats or houses? Some blocks of flats have "no pets" rules, so it might not even be the landlord's choice, could be the building

Comment: I'm actually looking for both. I know some developments have that kind of rules, but it looks like it's a general rule!

Comment: About the off topic on hold, could someone explain how to improve the question or why I'm being off topic? It's about moving to another country with pets…… <joke>Or is it that the expatriates SE has the same policy towards pets as UK landlords?</joke> :-)